# Using OpenType features with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick

Tags: unicode, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, opentype

Does anyone know if it's possible to use OpenType features in ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick? Specifically, I'm looking to use glyphs that are not assigned to Unicode points (glyphs are sometimes placed outside of the Unicode range, since they are intended to act as embellishments to other characters). In OpenType-aware desktop applications, you would usually need to open a glyph table and select the glyph manually; I'm not sure how you would do this using ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid, such advanced (and also: somehow obscure) OTF features are ***NOT*** (yet) supported by ImageMagick -- at least there's nothing in the available documentation (I don't know about GraphicsMagick).

But your best option to get a definitive, authoritative answer from the developers themselves is: [register here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=14) and ask again on the official ImageMagick *Users* list.